# Django - Field attributes in widget context

Tags: django, django-forms

As I am using some more exotic css framework I would like to change the behaviour of the text input (provide it with label etc. by default).

- I have overridden the template in `django/forms/widgets/input.html`

Unfortunately the widget context is missing the `field`, so I cannot use field properties like `help_text`, `label`, etc in my template. Therefore I would need to override the `TextInput` widget.

My two options are now:

- Setting my own widget class for every single field in my `Form` / `Modelform` classes
- Using My custom `ModelForm` which iterates all the fields in `__init__` and replaces the widget.
- **Is there any better way to override django's default** `text_input` **widget?**
- Does is there any other way to get `field.errors` and `field.label` into the widget
  (Or is there a reason why there is no label in the widget context)?